# GraphQL resolve mapping

Tags: graphql

I'm having an issue trying to write a field resolver when the parent source is coming from different sources and different shapes.

For example, assuming i have the following schema:

```
type Person
    id : Number
    fullname : String

type Story:
    title : String
    author : Person

Query:
    getPersonById(id: Number) : Person      #   makes db call.
    getStoryById(id: Number) : Story        #   gets the story somehow.
```

Now, the problem is with the Story's author resolver, the value it returns is:

```
{ id: 1, first_name: "Jack" last_name: "Hugh" }
```

while getPersonById returns:

```
{ id: 1, firstName: "Jack", lastName: "Hugh" }
```

and now, I cannot write a working resolver for Person's fullName as the field name in the source are different.

What would you suggest to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have data coming from different sources, I go with the approach of normalizing them as soon as I get them, I keep my resolver functions relatively simple.

You could easily write a resolver function that checks what the data shape is and does the right thing accordingly, but it's better if the data is already in the right shape.

My process is generally:

`DB/Service Query -> Transform/Normalize Data -> GraphQL type (with custom resolvers only for expensive fields)`